# Location of base directory of OpenMPI for cmake

Tags: cmake, installation, mpi, openmpi, trilinos

I am trying to compile Trilinos with MPI capabilities. But to specify the cmake command, i need to also specify the MPI base directory:

```
cmake \
-DTPL_ENABLE_MPI=ON \
-DMPI_BASE_DIR:FILEPATH="" \
-DTrilinos_ENABLE_PyTrilinos:BOOL=ON \
-DTrilinos_ENABLE_ALL_PACKAGES=ON \
-DTrilinos_ENABLE_TESTS:BOOL=ON \
-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS:BOOL=ON \
-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:STRING="$HOME/trilinos-install" \
$SOURCE_DIR
```

However, I am unable to find any base directory even though MPI is installed on my machine. When i enter commands like `mpirun --version`, I get:

```
mpirun (Open MPI) 2.1.1
```

or `ompi_info`:

```
 Package: Open MPI buildd@lcy01-amd64-009 Distribution
                Open MPI: 2.1.1
  Open MPI repo revision: v2.1.0-100-ga2fdb5b
   Open MPI release date: May 10, 2017
                Open RTE: 2.1.1
...
```

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on WSL if that is useful info.

Comment: How did you install Open MPI? Using `apt-get install`? If that is the case, you should see the Open MPI files in these directories `/usr/include/openmpi/` and `/usr/lib/openmpi/lib`.

Answer (score 0):

The command "which mpich" can give you the default directory of mpi installation.
Another way is to use mpic++ as the compiler in the CMake.